# packer: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-iam, packer, aws-roles

I'm facing a bit of a weird problem,  I'm writing a JSON file to configure Packer in order to build an AMI machine. Host OS is windows and machine OS is Ubuntu. I am using instance type: amazon-instance.
I am getting this error

> ==> amazon-instance: Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

I want to use a role to authenticate my user, so I used "assume_role" object from Packer documentation. But it is still not working.

```
 "assume_role": {
     "role_arn"    :  "{{user `role_arn_txt`}}",
     "session_name":  "Role12"
```

Does any one come across this problem?
Help would be super appreciated!
Thank you all!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a valid credentials file in the right place?

Comment: You still need credentials to assume the role, so those have to be supplied also.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! I already configured my credentials on my own computer. Now I need to assume a role to the machine that will create me the AMI. the weirdest thing is even if I write a static access_key and secret_key and then give a command like "was configure list" the machine still will send me a no set variable. I don't understand what I am doing wrong